# Ming 0.3.2 Installs and Imports but Crashes

Tags: mongodb, odm, ming

After installing Ming 0.3.2, I tested the installation by running the following code:

```
>>> from ming.datastore import DataStore
>>> bind = DataStore('mongodb://localhost:27017/', database='tutorial')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'database'
>>> ^D
```

I looked at the installation files and in the datastore.py file I found that the class's constructor did not contain a "database" argument.

```
class DataStore(object):

    def __init__(self, bind, name, authenticate=None):
        self.bind = bind
        self.name = name
        self._authenticate = authenticate
        self._db = None
```

I then installed Ming 0.3.0 to look at the datastore.py file and found the DataStore class to match the documentation (it contained a database arg) and then tried that version where I encountered other complications.

I use easy_install to install Ming and I have a good install of mongodb and pymongo running.  I  run these on OS X Lion.  Any advise on getting Ming running would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think there may be a conflict with the newest version of pymongo and ming.

bind = DataStore('mongodb://localhost:27017/', name='test') gets me a bit further along, but I ended up just using pymongo by itself.

Answer (score 2):

I've met the same issue. Here are the steps I've tried, and it works! Hopes it works for your environment too.

1. Uninstall the Ming 0.3.2 version by :  `pip uninstall Ming`
2. Install 0.3.0 by: `pip install -Iv http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/merciless/0.3.0/Ming-0.3.0.tar.gz`
3. Try the example on the Ming office website again. There will be another error

   > Traceback (most recent call last):
   >          File "tutorial.py", line 1, in <module>
   >             from ming.datastore import DataStore
   >          File "/home/me/work/deploy/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ming/**init**.py", line 3, in <module>
   >             from session import Session
   >          File "/home/me/work/deploy/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ming/session.py", line 7, in <module>
   >             from pymongo.son import SON
   >          ImportError: No module named son
4. change the line 7 of  "/home/me/work/deploy/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ming/session.py" to `from bson.son import SON`
5. try again. and it will works.

Here is the link I've referenced. It's a Japanese webpage, but you can translate it to English by google translator.
http://ryooo321.blogspot.com/2012/05/macsleepymongoose.html

Answer (score 0):

try to remove `database=`.

```
In [8]: from ming.datastore import DataStore

In [9]: bind = DataStore('mongodb://grid:27017/', 'tutorial')

In [10]: bind.name
Out[10]: 'tutorial'
```